# IF(F6<0,"Overdue By","Due In") if J6 doesnt contain date leave E6 Blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

My formula is in cell E6

`=IF(F6<0,"Overdue By","Due In")` - this works no problem

I want to leave E6 blank if cell J6 contains text (a date to be specific) I have tried IF(OR but I cannot get the result I require

Any help would be great

Comment: `=IF(J6<>"","",IF(F6<0,"Overdue By","Due In"))`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A date is just a number under the hood in Excel. So you could use

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(J6),"", IF(F6 < 0,"Overdue By","Due In"))
```